# Perspective plot using diagonally upper triangle of the corresponding matrix in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I am plotting 9 perspective plots in R using the below code where cm is a list of 9 matrices[11x11]. Now I would like to draw the perspective graph for diagonally upper triangle of each of the corresponding matrix. And also generalise the colour legend for the plots based on the maximum and minimum values (which I already have) from these 9 matrices.
Similar question using maptplotlib also answered in SO and I want a R version of it.

[Plotting only upper/lower triangle of a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318529/plotting-only-upper-lower-triangle-of-a-heatmap)

```
library(fields)

cm <- list()
i = 1
while(i <= 9){
  cm[[i]] <- matrix(runif(121), 11, 11)
  i = i + 1
}

methods <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
w_lb <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
w_dti <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)

with(cm, {
  par(mfrow=c(3,3), xpd=TRUE, bg="white")
  par(mar=c(2,1,2,1) + 0.1)

  i = 1
  while(i <= 9){
    nrz <- nrow(cm[[i]])
    ncz <- ncol(cm[[i]])    
    jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "darkred"))    
    nbcol <- 100
    color <- jet.colors(nbcol)    
    zfacet <- (cm[[i]][-1, -1] + cm[[i]][-1, -ncz] + cm[[i]][-nrz, -1] + cm[[i]][-nrz, -ncz])/4    
    facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)

    persp(w_lb, w_dti, cm[[i]], 
            theta = -30, phi = 30, expand = 0.85, 
            col=color[facetcol], shade = 0.25, 
            ticktype = "detailed", border = NA, 
            xlab = "LB", ylab = "DTI", zlab="CM", 
            zlim=c(0.0, 1.0)
    )

    image.plot(legend.only=T, zlim=range(zfacet), col=color)
    title(main = methods[[i]])
    i = i + 1    
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible? We don't have access to `cm`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik sorry for the late reply. I've added the code to generate `cm` using random values.