# Plot existing covariance dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, covariance-matrix

I have computed a covariance of 26 inputs from another software. I have an existing table of the results. See image below:
[image]

What I want to do is enter the table as a pandas dataframe and plot the matrix. I have seen the thread here: [Plot correlation matrix using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas). However, the aforementioned example, computed the covariance first and plotted the 'covariance' object. In my case, I want to plot the dataframe object to look like the covariance matrix in the example.

Link to data: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10RqmlH7T73kl_tgFyQJ0crhDwuazsQHyQEC5tbFPak8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: You can use seaborn.heatmap(name_of_your_dataframe) to do it. This feature of the seaborn library is often used to graphically display a correlation matrix.

Comment: And of course you can change the colors with the 'cmap' parameter. One of my favorites for covariance matrix: 'coolwarm'. Here - https://www.kaggle.com/code/asimislam/python-colors-color-cmap-palette you can find another pallets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#) with `annot=True` :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))

(
    pd.read_excel("/tmp/Covariance Matrix.xlsx", header=None)
        .pipe(lambda df: sns.heatmap(df.sample(10).sample(10, axis=1), annot=True, fmt=".1f"))
);

# for a sample of 10 rows / 10 columns
```

Output :

[image]

And, as suggested by [stukituk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20846785/stukituk) in the comments, you can add `cmap="coolwarm"` for colors :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a clean option, in my opinion, from this other answer: [How to plot only the lower triangle of a seaborn heatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414771/how-to-plot-only-the-lower-triangle-of-a-seaborn-heatmap)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('Covariance Matrix.xlsx', header=None)

# Getting the Upper Triangle of the co-relation matrix
matrix = np.triu(df)

# using the upper triangle matrix as mask 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax, fmt='.1g', annot=True, mask=matrix)
plt.show()
```

[image: triangular heatmap]

hope this helps