# Plotting a heatmap of dataframe values with 2 indices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've a dataset like this:

```
1 1 0.5378291300966559
1 2 0.5536607043661815
2 2 0.5524941673147428
1 3 0.5736584823908455
2 3 0.5759360071103211
3 3 0.5874347294745028
1 4 0.5926563715142762
2 4 0.5928230196644817
3 4 0.5994333962893011
4 4 0.6093211865348295
1 5 0.6073769581157649
2 5 0.6092100877680258
3 5 0.6138206865903788
4 5 0.6182646372625263
5 5 0.6275413842906343
```

The goal is to plot out a heatmap of the values where the first 2 columns are the axis and the 3rd is the value.

I've read them out so that it fits into the dataframe a pivoted it:

```
data_str = """1 1 0.5378291300966559
1 2 0.5536607043661815
2 2 0.5524941673147428
1 3 0.5736584823908455
2 3 0.5759360071103211
3 3 0.5874347294745028
1 4 0.5926563715142762
2 4 0.5928230196644817
3 4 0.5994333962893011
4 4 0.6093211865348295
1 5 0.6073769581157649
2 5 0.6092100877680258
3 5 0.6138206865903788
4 5 0.6182646372625263
5 5 0.6275413842906343""".split('\n')

import pandas as pd


data = [{'min':line.split()[0], 'max':line.split()[1], 'score':line.split()[2]} for line in data_str]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=float).pivot('min', 'max', 'score')
```

When I tried out the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173863/610569, it only showed a straight line like:

[image]

But what I am expecting is for it to plot out the triangle heatmap of the values I have in the score column. How should I go about the plotting that?

Comment: Is this data from a file?

Answer (score 1):

The function name is `get_lower_tri_heatmap` which will be the lower tri, in your df

```
df#upper tri 
Out[101]: 
max       1.0       2.0       3.0       4.0       5.0
min                                                  
1.0  0.537829  0.553661  0.573658  0.592656  0.607377
2.0       NaN  0.552494  0.575936  0.592823  0.609210
3.0       NaN       NaN  0.587435  0.599433  0.613821
4.0       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.609321  0.618265
5.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.627541
```

Try pass `df.T` to the function

```
get_lower_tri_heatmap(df.T)
```

Comment: Not sure why if I transpose the bottom of the y-axis starts from the 5 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first define an empty numpy array before assigning the values into it. Should look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((5, 5))
t = """1 1 0.5378291300966559
1 2 0.5536607043661815
2 2 0.5524941673147428
1 3 0.5736584823908455
2 3 0.5759360071103211
3 3 0.5874347294745028
1 4 0.5926563715142762
2 4 0.5928230196644817
3 4 0.5994333962893011
4 4 0.6093211865348295
1 5 0.6073769581157649
2 5 0.6092100877680258
3 5 0.6138206865903788
4 5 0.6182646372625263
5 5 0.6275413842906343"""
for line in t.splitlines():
    a[int(line.split()[0]) - 1][int(line.split()[1]) - 1] = line.split()[2]
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```